# How to copy and add prefix to file names in one step?

Tags: bash, cp, file-copy

I want to copy and rename multiple c source files in a directory.

I can copy like this:

```
$ cp *.c $OTHERDIR
```

But I want to give a prefix to all the file names:

```
file.c --> old#file.c
```

How can I do this in 1 step?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

a `for` loop:

```
for f in *.c; do cp -- "$f" "$OTHERDIR/old#$f"; done
```

I often add the `-v` option to `cp` to allow me to watch the progress.

Answer (score 8):

You can use shell globbing:

```
for f in *.c; do cp -- "$f" "$OTHERDIR/old#$f"; done
```

The `for variable in GLOB` format will expand the [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) to all matching files/directories (excluding hidden-ones) and iterate over them, saving each in turn as `$variable` (in the example above, `$f`). So, the command I show will iterate over all non-hidden files, copying them and adding the prefix.

Comment: If I do `for f in /foo/bar/*.c`, `$f` will contain the entire path, instead only the name of the file. How can I obtain only the name of the file?

Comment: @alexandernst either `cd /foo/bar/; for f in *c`, or use `for f in /foo/bar/*.c; do name=${f##*/} ...` or `name=$(basename "$f")`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner using `xargs`, `tr` and globbing. Might have some value.

```
echo *.c | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs -n1 -I{} cp "{}" "PREFIX{}"
```

This returns all files matching `*.c` as a space-separated string. Next, `tr` turns the extra spaces into newlines (*N.B.* did not test file names with spaces**). Then, `xargs` gets populated with each file name, and runs `cp` with the appropriate name and prefix.

`*.c` can be modified for other, useful globs. Other prefixes in the `xargs` and `cp` part can be used as well.

## **for those with spaces in their filenames:

(requires `find` that supports `-print0`)
Similar to above, we can use `find` to output a *null*-seperated list of files, and tweak `xargs` with a flag to separate on *null*

```
find . -name '*.c' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} cp "{}" "PREFIX{}"
```

Comment: And, if you ***had*** tested this with filenames containing spaces, you would have seen it fail.

Comment: Thanks for call-out. I knew it probably failed but thought I had already procrastinated through enough of my workday with the first pass. 

Answer (score 0):

Still another way:

```
for f in $(find dir/ -type f | grep -v 'bk_'); do cp -- "$f" "$(dirname $f)/bk_$(pwgen -s 4 1)_$(basename $f)"; done
```

Each time you run this way, it will turn dir/ from:

```
dir/foo/foo.c
dir/bar/bar.c
dir/baz/baz.c
```

Into:

```
dir/foo/foo.c
dir/foo/bk_R3pP_foo.c
dir/bar/bar.c
dir/bar/bk_o1JD_bar.c
dir/baz/baz.c
dir/baz/bk_0QqF_baz.c
```

And then:

```
dir/foo/foo.c
dir/foo/bk_R3pP_foo.c
dir/foo/bk_dV06_foo.c
dir/bar/bar.c
dir/bar/bk_o1JD_bar.c
dir/bar/bk_B68i_bar.c
dir/baz/baz.c
dir/baz/bk_0QqF_baz.c
dir/baz/bk_p6P3_baz.c
```

And then...:

```
dir/foo/foo.c
dir/foo/bk_R3pP_foo.c
dir/foo/bk_dV06_foo.c
dir/foo/bk_2Ar8_foo.c
dir/bar/bar.c
dir/bar/bk_o1JD_bar.c
dir/bar/bk_B68i_bar.c
dir/bar/bk_wX7Z_bar.c
dir/baz/baz.c
dir/baz/bk_0QqF_baz.c
dir/baz/bk_p6P3_baz.c
dir/baz/bk_fPd3_baz.c
```

.. and so on.

Comment: [Don't loop over `find`'s output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697). Don't use `grep` to exclude file names when `find` alone can do it.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how one would do it recursively if needed,

```
for f in `find . -name \*.c`; do name="${f//\.\//__}"; fileName="${name//\//_}" ; echo "Copying $f as $OTHERDIR/old#$fileName"; cp -- "$f" "$OTHERDIR/$fileName"; done
```

Comment: Same here,  [don't loop over `find`'s output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)